# Handle position changes are discarded upon Play

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a `ProbeManager` where I can move around probes using `Handles`. Here is my `MonoBehaviour` and its `Custom Editor`:

MonoBehaviour:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ProbeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Probe[] probes;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Probe
    {
        public Vector3 pos;
        public float radius;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        for (int i = 0; i < probes.Length; i++)
        {
            Probe probe = probes[i];
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(probe.pos, probe.radius);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Editor:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ProbeManager))]
public class ProbeManagerEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }

    protected virtual void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        ProbeManager probe_manager = (ProbeManager)target;

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        for (int i = 0; i < probe_manager.probes.Length; i++)
        {
            probe_manager.probes[i].pos = Handles.PositionHandle(probe_manager.probes[i].pos, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck();
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I change probes' properties be it `radius` or `position` through **Inspector** it works fine. But when I try to move them aroung with **Handles** they teleport back to its previous position after I press `Play`.

I suspect it has something to do with serialization but thats it :(

Answer (score 0):

I should have done this through `serializedObject`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;
[CustomEditor(typeof(ProbeManager))]
public class ProbeManagerEditor : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty probes_prop;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        probes_prop = serializedObject.FindProperty("probes");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }

    protected virtual void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        ProbeManager probe_manager = (ProbeManager)target;

        for (int i = 0; i < probe_manager.probes.Length; i++)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            Vector3 position = Handles.PositionHandle(probe_manager.probes[i].pos, Quaternion.identity);

            SerializedProperty probe = probes_prop.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            SerializedProperty probe_pos = probe.FindPropertyRelative("pos");
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck() == true)
            {
                probe_pos.vector3Value = position;
                serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
        }
    }
}
```